# Random problems with definition

Tags: c++, linux

I am trying to compile my code. The compiler is giving random errors about 'multiple definition':

> /tmp/cctnjqVc.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of 'firstname'
>   /tmp/ccPgFuZw.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
>   /tmp/cctnjqVc.o:(.bss+0x200): multiple definition of 'resultName[abi:cxx11]'
>   /tmp/ccPgFuZw.o:(.bss+0x200): first defined here

I can assure you that there is no multiple definition at all in my code.
My code is in multiple files so if you want to see them all:

http://www.github.com/calmunicorn/virtualsociety

but there are two files that I think are concerned:

#### FileStream.h

```
#ifndef FILESTREAM_H
#define FILESTREAM_H
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;
static fstream logFile;
ofstream firstname;
void log(string argument);
string firstName_read(bool boyOrGirl);
string resultName;

#endif
```

#### FileStream.cpp

```
#include "FileStream.h"
void log(string argument)
{
    logFile.open ("log.txt", fstream::out | fstream::app);

    logFile << argument;

    logFile.close();
}

string firstName_read (bool boyOrGirl)
{

    if (boyOrGirl == true)
         {
              firstname.open("Name/FirstName_Male.txt", fstream::in);
              firstname.close();
              return resultName;
         }
    else
         {
              firstname.open("Name/FirstName_Female.txt", fstream::in);
              firstname.close();
              return resultName;
         }
}
```

I'm on Arch Linux if makes any difference.

---

edit :

Thank you for all the answer i did everything  i was told to and now it work without any problems!

Comment: Note that each file that includes `FileStream.h` gets its own, independent `logFile` variable — which is probably not what you intended. Each such file also defines global variables `firstname` and `resultname` — which is going to lead to 'multiple definition' problems.

Answer (score 2):

You did [violate ODR](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rs-inline) by defining (as opposed to just declaring) `firstname` and `resultName` in the header. What you need to do, to declare them, is to list them as `extern` in the header file:

```
extern ofstream firstname;
extern string resultName;
```

and have the definition (without `extern`) in the `.cpp` file.

BTW, [headers **should not** use `using namespace`](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rs-using-directive). Explicitly qualify everything in your header, instead.

Answer (score 1):

This line in `FileStream.h`

```
ofstream firstname;
```

will define a variable `firstname` in each .cpp file that includes the .h.

You probably want to change that to a *declaration* in the .h

```
extern ofstream firstname;
```

then define it in just one of the .cpp files

```
ofstream firstname;
```